# Redirect user to login page when session expires in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I am trying to redirect a user back to the login page if their session has expired. I am using Laravel 5.5. I have edited my `RedirectIfAuthenticated` file to include the following code in the `handle` function:

```
if (!Auth::check()) {
    return redirect()->route('login', ['account' => 'demo']);
}
```

When I do this, I am receiving the following error message:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: /].

My `login` route is inside a subdomain route group which is why I am passing the `account` parameter. Here is part of my code in `web.php`

```
// Subdomain routing
Route::domain('{account}.ems.dev')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'LoginController@show')->name('login');
}
```

And here is my `LoginController@show` code:

```
/*
 * Show the login form
 */
public function show($account) {
    // Validate this is a valid subdomain
    $organization = Organization::where('subdomain', $account)->first();

    if ($organization) { 
        return view('login');
    } else {
        return 'This account does not exist.';
    }
}
```

Nothing I have tried works. I keep getting the exact same error message even though I am passing in the required parameters.

### Update #1

Screenshot of error page:

[image]

### Update #2

After a little digging around the *Whoops!* error page, I see this, `protected function unauthenticated` is what is causing the problem:

[image]

How do I override this function to add the missing parameter?

Comment: Did you try to clear route cache? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @AndriySushchyk Yes, I tried that but still received the same error message. Any other thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: How is `LoginController@show` defined?

Comment: @Camilo Just updated the original post to show that code.

Comment: Are you sure the error is being thrown at the line you think it is? Everything looks fine for me.

Comment: @Camilo Just updated the original post to show the screenshot of the error.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't really show where the error started. Could it be you are calling this route from somewhere else?

Comment: @Camilo I am not sure to be honest. I only receive this error when a user is not logged in. When I am logged in, all of the routes work without any errors.

Comment: Comment that line out and try to reproduce the problem. If the same problem persists, I would look for the cause somewhere else. If not, then there is something we are not seeing.

Comment: @Camilo Sorry, had to step out for a bit. I commented out that line like you said to and still the same error message. Someone else suggested that I try this: `return redirect()->route('login', ['demo']);` however that did not work either. I am soooo stumped it is driving me crazy lol.

Comment: @Camilo, please check updated post to see if the new information helps. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the `unauthenticated()` method in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file to add the missing route parameter.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('login', ['account' => $request->route('account')]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this and now I am receiving a new error message (this is progress :) The new error message is: `ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException $exception) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)`.

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;` to your `Handler.php` file.

Comment: Awesome, no more error messages! However, there is one slight issue. The value of `account` is different for each user in my system. How do I get the `account` from the URL for proper redirection? For example, if the user's login URL is https://acme.ems.dev how do I get the `acme` part so that it will redirect to **their** login screen?

Comment: I just tried this and it redirects me to `https://ems.dev:8888/`. It simply removes the subdomain. Any other suggestions? We are close to figuring it out :)

Comment: I also tried `request()->input('account')` but no luck either, same result.

Comment: Try `$request->route('account')`.

Comment: this solved my issue! Thank you very, very much for all of your help!

Comment: i tried similar method i put if $exception is an instance of AuthenticationException then redirect to login with some message like session has been expired,but now what happening is every time i visit login page it tell me session has expired.

Comment: @Linus Try this approach instead.